# URL doesn't appear when i use Header tag?

Tags: php, url

When I use the header command, it sends me to the page I wanted but the URL doesn't change. Is this normal behavior?

Here is my code :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND Password='$password'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($row['username']==$username && $row['Password']==$password){

    $_SESSION["name"]= $row['username'];
    $_SESSION["id"]= $row['id'];

  header('Location: home.php');
  }
  else {
    header('Location:login.php');
  }
```

My URL still displays as the same with different page it is still :

```
http://localhost/JQueryMobileTest/
```

Instead of

`http://localhost/JQueryMobileTest/home.php`

I want the URL to appear as the page being displayed, what is my problem???

Comment: You are saying that you are redirected to `home.php` but the value in the address bar doesn't change ?

Comment: I would suggest adding `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script; I'm guessing that there's output before the `header()` call.

Comment: yes i am redirected to home.php but the url doesn't change

Comment: what error_reporting(-1); do ???

Comment: Are you using an `iframe`?

Comment: Look at the responses from the server with Firebug or similar. You should see a `Location: http://localhost/JQueryMobileTest/home.php` header if the redirect is working correctly.